# Add Title before Export Excel

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel, c#-4.0, c#-3.0

Am using the Following Function for Export the Excel File.It Was working Fine.I retrieve the Records from SQL DataBase to data table and I Export the Excel Sheet.

```
        public ActionResult ExporttoExcel()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Connection string here");
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Exportxcel", con);
            dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
            int total = 0;
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                int salaryvalue = Convert.ToInt32(row["Salary"]);
                total = salaryvalue + total;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "", "Total", total });


            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                string filename = "ExcelExport.xls";
                System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter();
                System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw = new System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw);
                DataGrid dgGrid = new DataGrid();
                dgGrid.DataSource = dt;
                dgGrid.DataBind();
                dgGrid.RenderControl(hw);
                Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
                Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + filename + "");
                Response.Write(tw.ToString());
                Response.End();
            }
             return View(dt);
        }
```

[image]

My question is I need to add Two title before the Value Bind?How to do this?I need to add Title ,author like the following Screen Shot.How to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try adding this just after declaring System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter hw

```
hw.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='3'>Title</td></tr>")
hw.Write("<table><tr><td colspan='3'>Author</td></tr>")
```